# Keeping Records That Are Not Joined MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following query in my application:

```
SELECT
p.old_product_id,
l.product_id,
p.sku,
p.title,
p.option_one,
p.option_two,
FROM
lookup_id l
JOIN temp_price_tables_data p USING (sku);
```

And it works great. However, a small percentage of records from the temp_price_tables_data tables don't make it to the results.

This is because the skus from the lookup_id table don't exist in the temp_price_tables_data.

Is there a way to keep these records in the new data?

Or is there a way to only get those records so I can store the result for later processing?

EDIT:

First table columns = old_product_id, sku, title, option_one, option_two

Second table column = product_id, sku

Tables should have SKU in common.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN`/`RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: What is "the new data"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left outer join:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
lookup_id l
LEFT OUTER JOIN price_tables_data p on l.sku = p.sku
WHERE old_product_id IS NULL;
```

That will get you all the records that are in temp_price_tables_data but not in lookup_id

Comment: Unfortunately, the tables do not both have the product_id field so this didn't work, I've added the columns in the OP

Comment: I've got it, thanks to your help, I'll edit your answer with changed solution for this situation, thanks :)

Comment: I see. I didn't realize that. Thanks for editing. (I initially rejected the edit - I didn't know it was you. But now I changed it back to your edit).